# WinForms DataBinding with DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I though I would post this as after spending several hours trying to work it out I am getting nowhere.  Firstly, I am fully aware that databinding in WinForms is not the best.  That said it does work in most scenarios.

In my scenario, I have a binding source which is the master for my form.  The object that is used for this binding source has a few simple properties and two binding lists as properties as well.  Both this class, and the class type for the binding lists implement INotifyPropertyChanged.  On my form, I have two DataGridViews for displaying the contents of the binding list properties.

This is also done through databinding at design time.  I have two binding sources for each which use the main binding source as there data source and then the respective bindinglist properties as the data member.

So far, I would consider this to be fairly standard.

To update what is in these lists I have buttons to show a form that creates a new item, which I then add to the lists using BindingList.Add().

Now in code, if you debug, the items are in the lists, however, the grids are not updating.
But if I add a listbox to the form which uses just one of the list binding sources then both of the grids start refreshing as expected.

I apologise if any of this is unclear, I have tried to explain as best as I can with a confusing situation.

Any thoughts would be helpful as I really don't want to have to use a hidden list box.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me or not but I didn't understand if all the object binded implement ***INotifyPropertyChanged***

Comment: Yes, all the objects that are being databound implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works fine for me

```
BindingList<Foo> source; // = ...
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = source };
    this.dataGridView2.DataSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = source, DataMember = "Children" };
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    source.Add(new Foo { X = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    source[0].Children.Add(new FooChild { Y = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
}
```

with the model

```
public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    string x;
    public string X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            x = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    BindingList<FooChild> children;
    public BindingList<FooChild> Children
    {
        get { return children; }
        set
        {
            children = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public class FooChild : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    string y;
    public string Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            y = value;
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Both grids get refreshed.

I hope this helps you

**Edit**

I changed the **Form1_Load** impl

Comment: I essentially have the same scenario, the only difference is rather than setting the datasource on the grid as a bindinglist, I set it to a BindingSource instead, as other parts of the BindingSource are used for other elements of the form.  Also, I'm trying to limit the amount of code in the form as it doesn't work well for unit testing.  But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ok, I edited my example for BindingSource. I don't know if you coded but I find important that your Children property to be BindingList or maybe ObservableCollection since you have to notify not only Children assignement but also additions